# Is WWW::Facebook::API going to stop working?

Tags: perl, facebook, perl-module

I recently came upon some old code which I didn't write. It uses [WWW::Facebook::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aFacebook%3a%3aAPI) to login via Facebook to our website. It currently only calls [WWW::Facebook::API::Users](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aFacebook%3a%3aAPI%3a%3aUsers) to get the user's info.

Now, my doubt is if I have to update this code to support the new [OAuth 2.0 method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) or the newer [Facebook Graph](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Facebook%3a%3aGraph). According to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/), the legacy Auth method is going to stop working on September. However, I don't know if WWW::Facebook::API uses this method. As far as I can tell, it does not pass any user's information to the browser, as it does server-to-server authentication. Has anybody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using this CPAN module and it is still working so I would answer my question. WWW::Facebook::API does not seem to have stopped working.